# increase accelerometer sensor sensitivity, and increase the brightness screen when the phone is shaken

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I would like to implement in this piece of code some instructions to increase the sensitivity of the accelerometer sensor, and increase the brightness of the screen when the phone is shaken

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
sensorManager.registerListener(this,         sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {                                     getAccelerometer(event);
}
}   
private void getAccelerometer(SensorEvent event) {
super.onResume();
float[] values = event.values;
// Movement
float x = values[0];
float y = values[1];
float z = values[2];
float accelationSquareRoot = (x * x + y * y + z * z)
/ (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH * SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (accelationSquareRoot >= 2) //
{
if (actualTime - lastUpdate < 200) {            
return;
}           
lastUpdate = actualTime;            
Toast.makeText(this, "Device was shuffed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying() == false){ 
mMediaPlayer.start();               
}
}
}
```

Comment: times the data by a certain value and then take only the values between -n to n where n*value is your new sensitivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int stretch = 50;
int boundary = 5;

float x = values[0];
float y = values[1];
float z = values[2];

x *= stretch;
y *= stretch;
z *= stretch;

if (x > 5 || x < -5) 
   x = 0;
if (y > 5 || y < -5) 
   y = 0;
if (z > 5 || z < -5) 
   z = 0;
```

just a very basic filter

as far as screen brightness goes :

```
private void setBrightness(int brightness) {  
try {  
  IHardwareService hardware = IHardwareService.Stub.asInterface(  
  ServiceManager.getService("hardware"));  
  if (hardware != null) {  
    hardware.setScreenBacklight(brightness);  
  }  
} catch (RemoteException doe) {            
  }          
}
```

Comment: on sensor changed is where you should be getting your values